# SQL Query for specific value in each of multiple records

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question involving a one-to-many relationship.

I have a table in my database called **Checklist**. Each checklist record can have multiple matches in the table for **ChecklistMaterial**. The **ChecklistMaterial** table has a field that indicates whether it was shipped or not using a 1 or 0 in a particular field indicated shipped or not shipped.

At the **Checklist** level I want to indicate (in a SQL statement that is pulling other **Checklist** fields) whether or not all materials for that checklist have been shipped. Basically, it would show a 1 at the checklist level if *all* material records for that checklist have been shipped.

This is a simple version of what I am trying to do. Let me know if this sounds completely off-base or a reasonable and appropriate approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
select
    checklist.abc,
    checklist.def,
    (select sign(sum(shipped))
       from checklistmaterials
      where checklist.checklistid = checklistmaterials.checklistid
from
    checklist
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure `ChecklistMaterial` only has `0` or `1`, the a minimum over this column would calculate if all records have 1.

```
SELECT * ,
      (SELECT Min(checked)
         FROM ChecklistMaterial
        WHERE <JOIN between Checklist and ChecklistMaterial>
      )
  FROM Checklist
```

BTW. Using `Max` instead of `Min` would check if at least one record has a `1`.

Comment: Sorry, it can actually be a 1 or 2 depending on the type of shipment. (It is connected to an option box in MS Access). So will Min(ChecklistMaterial) always equal 0 if only one material is 0?

Comment: @user3177831 `Min(ChecklistMaterial)` is the minimum value found on all records that fulfill the join condition, i. e. in case you have 1 and 2 in the column, it would be 1 if there is at least one 1, and 2 if there are only 2s in the records selected by the WHERE.

Comment: Oh yes, that does make sense now.. Hmm. I might be stuck.